# For vuforia support in unity, how do I change the button color?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

```
public class viewModel : MonoBehaviour {

    public void B_Start(Button button)
    {   
        //Changes the button's Normal color to the new color.
        ColorBlock cb = button.colors;
        cb.normalColor = Color.black;
        button.colors = cb;
    }


    // Use this for initialization
    public void Button_Click () {
        Debug.Log("Hello World");
    }

}
```

The above code changes the color of a button in a 2D Unity environment. But when I use the same code in Vuforia AR with Unity, why does the code not work?

Comment: More info would help. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: No, it runs perfectly. Just when I open the application and click the button, the color of the button which is supposed to change, does not. Basically nothing happens.